# ¡Qué sucede si escribo otra anotación diferente a la Base de Datos en Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Tengo una consulta, si por ejemplo en la Base de Datos dos tablas están relacionadas con una relación 1:1 (uno es a uno), y en la aplicación ocupo por ejemplo @ManyToOne para relacionar esas dos Entidades, al momento de ejecutar la aplicación no salta ningún error, pero, se modificará la Base de Datos? o no se modifica la Base de Datos pero habrá una inconsistencia en la aplicación?
Por ejemplo tengo esta Base de Datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui esta mi Clase Vacante:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Vacantes")
public class Vacante {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // auto_increment MySQL
private Integer id;
private String nombre; 
private String descripcion; 
private Date fecha; 
private Double salario; 
private String estatus; 
private Integer destacado;
private String imagen="no-image.png";
private String detalles; 

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idCategoria") // foreignKey en la tabla de Vacantes 
private Categoria categoria; // Categoria a la que pertence la oferta de trabajo

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getEstatus() {
    return estatus;
}

public void setEstatus(String estatus) {
    this.estatus = estatus;
}

public Integer getDestacado() {
    return destacado;
}

public void setDestacado(Integer destacado) {
    this.destacado = destacado;
}

public String getImagen() {
    return imagen;
}

public void setImagen(String imagen) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
}

public String getDetalles() {
    return detalles;
}

public void setDetalles(String detalles) {
    this.detalles = detalles;
}

public Categoria getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}

public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}   

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public Double getSalario() {
    return salario;
}

public void setSalario(Double salario) {
    this.salario = salario;
}

public void reset() {
    this.imagen=null;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Vacante [id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", descripcion=" + descripcion + ", fecha=" + fecha
            + ", salario=" + salario + ", estatus=" + estatus + ", destacado=" + destacado + ", imagen=" + imagen
            + ", detalles=" + detalles + ", categoria=" + categoria + "]";
}
```

}

Como se ve en el ejemplo en el modelo relacional la tabla Vacantes tiene una relacion muchos es a uno (N:1) hacia la tabla Categorias, pero en la aplicacion de Spring Boot se le da una relaciòn @OneToOne hacia la Clase Categoria y funciona igual, sin problemas.

Si cambio la relación por @ManyToOne

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Vacantes")
public class Vacante {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // auto_increment MySQL
private Integer id;
private String nombre; // Nombre de la oferta de trabajo.
private String descripcion; // Descripcion corta de la oferta de trabajo
private Date fecha; // Fecha de publicacion de la oferta del trabajo.
private Double salario; // Salario aproximado que se ofrece por el trabajo.
private String estatus; // Valores [Creado, Aprobado, Eliminado].
private Integer destacado; // Valores [0, 1]. 0: No se muestra en la pag. principal | 1: Se muestra en la pagina principal.
private String imagen="no-image.png"; // Nombre del archivo de la imagen del logotipo de la empresa que ofrece el trabajo.
private String detalles; // Detalles de la oferta de trabajo.

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idCategoria") // foreignKey en la tabla de Vacantes 
private Categoria categoria; // Categoria a la que pertence la oferta de trabajo

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getEstatus() {
    return estatus;
}

public void setEstatus(String estatus) {
    this.estatus = estatus;
}

public Integer getDestacado() {
    return destacado;
}

public void setDestacado(Integer destacado) {
    this.destacado = destacado;
}

public String getImagen() {
    return imagen;
}

public void setImagen(String imagen) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
}

public String getDetalles() {
    return detalles;
}

public void setDetalles(String detalles) {
    this.detalles = detalles;
}

public Categoria getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}

public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}   

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public Double getSalario() {
    return salario;
}

public void setSalario(Double salario) {
    this.salario = salario;
}

public void reset() {
    this.imagen=null;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Vacante [id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", descripcion=" + descripcion + ", fecha=" + fecha
            + ", salario=" + salario + ", estatus=" + estatus + ", destacado=" + destacado + ", imagen=" + imagen
            + ", detalles=" + detalles + ", categoria=" + categoria + "]";
}
```

}

Si  cambio la relacion en la aplicacion por @ManyToOne tambien funciona correctamente. Mi pregunta es si la aplicación funciona correctamente tanto con @OneToOne y @ManyToOne, ¿Cuá es técnicamente el cambio, se harán mas solicitudes con una configuración que con otra? ¿ O la aplicación funcionará pero no como debería? ¿En algún momento saltará alguna Exception? Spy nuevo en JPA.
Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Depende de los datos, de cómo esté implementada esa relación 1-1 en la base de datos, etc. Esencialmente, saltarán errores cuando la BD valide una integridad que la aplicación no. En su formato actual, la pregunta es muy amplia porque no hay detalles d ela implementación

Comment: lo normal es que te marque un error porque tus tablas ya existen y no puede realizar las operaciones como le dices. Para modificar la base de datos debes hacerlo mediante configuracion... pero eso es otra preguta asi que voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es demasiado amplia y no tiene un [mcve]

Comment: Usando @ManyToOne para una relación donde solo hay una entidad relacionada con otra, la aplicación puede tener problemas para manejar los datos de manera correcta, ya que esta anotación se utiliza para relaciones donde una entidad está conectada a muchas otra en resumen en Spring Boot puede tener errores de integridad en los datos. Podrías colocar que es lo que intentas hacer y asi te podemos dar errores específicos.